# Calendar - display month and decade only

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like the calendar control to only display the month and decade as the day is not needed. On start up the calendar control's date is set to today's date. This is what I have:

**XAML :**

```
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding FromMonthYear}" Name="FromCalendar" DisplayMode="{Binding CalendarDisplayMode}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DisplayModeChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnCalendarDisplayModeCommand}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FromCalendar, Path=DisplayMode}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DisplayDateChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnCalendarDisplayDateCommand}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FromCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>                        
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Calendar>


<Button Content="Run Report" Name="RunReportButton" 
        Command="{Binding OnRunReportCommand}" />
```

**C# :**

```
private DateTime _fromMonthYear;
public DateTime FromMonthYear
{
    get { return _fromMonthYear; }
    set { Set(() => FromMonthYear, ref _fromMonthYear, value); }
}
private void OnRunReportPress()
{
    var d = FromMonthYear;
}
private void OnCalendarDisplayModeChange()
{
    CalendarDisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}
private void OnCalendarDisplayDateChange(object date)
{
    var d = FromMonthYear;
}
```

I have two problems. The first is when the display mode is set to a year clicking on the year in the calendar does not display the decades but the left and right arrows do switch the year. The second problem is that the FromMonthYear property does not get updated with the date picked when the OnReportReportPress and OnCalendarDisplayDateChange methods get executed. How can these two problems be resolved? Thanks

Comment: when you change your date, the Set for FromMonthYear is triggered?

Comment: Looks like the Set method only gets triggered when I can can pick a day by commenting out the CalendarDisplayMode = Calendar.Year statement.

Comment: The Calendar class does seem to have a DisplayMonthChanged Event. The OnCalendarDisplayDateChange method gets triggered when a month is picked but because the Set method on the FromMonthYear property is not the date is not updated.

Comment: OnCalendarDisplayDateChange(object date) <-- is this date the new one?

Comment: It should be yes but I added this method just for experimentation. What I want is the FromMonthYear property to be what the month and year selected is when the OnRunReportPress method gets triggered, which is triggered by a button.

Comment: as far as I see, and if i understand the problem, when you change month you have to set a default date in that month/year (the first day or so...). Do maybe on the DisplayMonthChanged set FromMonthYear with that date!